# Can there be more than one Red Black Tree possible for a given keys?

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

In case possible, please provide me an example.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for example, just with the keys 1 and 2 you can have:

1b
  2r

or

2b
1r

Answer (score 0):

Here's two different valid RB-trees with keys {1,2}:

```
  2:B       1:B
  /           \
1:R           2:R
```